# Count of a number in the entire sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I am using Excel 2013. In column B, I have (from B1:B229) different order numbers. I would like to see as I copied another report on the Excel sheet if all order numbers are present. Is there a way to create a formula (probably `countif`, but I did not figure it out) that would return 1 if the number is present only in column B or 2 (2 should be the max and would mean that it was copied correctly). The copied report is a bit messy and therefore the order numbers  for that one are not aligned in the same column (can be preset in column L,M,N until Q). That is why I cannot use `Vlookup`.

Any suggestion for formulas to count the number of times a specific number appears in an entire sheet? and then drag that formula down for the rest of the numbers present in column B?

This image is showing you 1 row of my table. The first column that you see is B. I would like to know if that number is anywhere else in the sheet (it should in one of the other columns where there is Invoice#:)

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you please include images for a working example of what you want? In it's current state your question is unclear to me

Comment: "Any suggestion for formulas to count the number of times a specific number appears in an entire sheet?" Yes, for this you need `COUNTIF`. Give it a try and let us know where you get stuck.

Comment: Just edited the question with an image. As for the COUNTIF since it is the entire sheet not specific columns how would I do that?

Comment: It seems you only have a few columns where you can find those values, as you write "can be preset in column L,M,N until Q". This is not an entire sheet. `COUNTIF` works perfectly fine for a range bigger than one column.

Comment: `=COUNTIF([range],[criteria])` should get you started. For more information on basic formula functionality, consulting Excel documentation either online or in the app's own help would be a good step.

Comment: I was more thinking towards Sum and If together... is that possible?

Comment: I have this formula =COUNTIF($I$1:$R$2355,B1) and it returns 0 but the value in B1 is present 2 times... I do not eve have an error message.. so why?

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that each row has a different order number, and you want to verify that the complete set of order numbers are an exact match, although they may be in a different order.  A simple count doesn't guarantee that, unless you count and compare each order number.  For example, each list could contain the same number of records, but each could contain order numbers not in the other, or there could be typos in the order numbers.  Counting for a specific order number verifies that one number, but not the entire list.  Can you clarify the requirement?

Comment: That is correct, I am actually looking to compare the 2 lists and see what are the differences between the 2. I wanted to count how many times an order number appears in the sheet because if it appears once instead of twice it is an error as it is not present in the second list and  moreover, I would know which order number has errors. If you have a different approach to compare two lists please let me know and also if this helped clarified the problem a bit.

Comment: For values, which are present, but `countif` doesn't seem to find them, check them manually. Like `=B1=J15`, or whatever cell you think is the same as B1. You might have trailing spaces or other invisible characters which makes the cells not equal in which case `countif` would not find them. `COUNTIF` only compares full cell contents with other cell's full contents. You will need another approach if you want to find matches where, e.g. your B1=`57919074` and J15=`the number is 57919074`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first. I see you are new and you have not accepted any answer in any of the Stack Exchange sites, while you had several questions asked. Part of the reason is poor formatting of your questions, so that people can't quickly understand what is your issue. Part of the reason for that - you have not read the [Tour page](https://superuser.com/tour) on any site.

Read FULL our [Tour page](https://superuser.com/tour). Then you will be able to ask questions in a better manner, so we will have more willingness to answer them. You want that, right?

---

I have tried several options of `COUNTIF`, but I didn't like it, because I wasn't able to get reliable results on partial match when the criterion is of numeric format. So I have created a UDF (user defined function) using VBA.

1. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to open VBA editor.
2. Insert a new module: Insert > Module. You should see a new empty Module there now.
   [image: VBA editor new module]
3. Paste there this code:

```
Public Function CountInRange(rWhere As Range, rCriterion As Range) As Long
  Dim c As Range, sCrit As String
  If rCriterion.Count  1 Then
    Err.Raise (13)
    Exit Function
  End If
  sCrit = rCriterion.Value
  For Each c In rWhere
    If Len(c.Value)  Len(Replace(c.Value, sCrit, vbNullString)) Then
      CountInRange = CountInRange + 1
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

4. Try using the function in your Excel worksheet by entering it as usual, e.g.:

```
=CountInRange($I$1:$R$2355,B1)
```

My results look like this:
[image: Excel VBA UDF results]

<sup>Note: now you will not be able to store the file using .xlsx extension. You can use e.g. **.xlsm**, in order for the file to store the UDF.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it. I will definitely read those pages so I know what to do in the future. For the VBA, I get an error #VALUE! after runnning it, how do we fix that please?

Comment: 2 things that I can think of. 1. Do you supply 1 cell as the second argument? It will give you this error if you supply more than one cell. 2. Try testing in in another sheet on some example data, just to see if it works. If it does not, you should find a way to enable macros/VBA, because by default they may be disabled (i.e. no code can run) even on .xlsm files..

Comment: I had 2 cells as second argument. That was my bad, your VBA works now perfectly thank you so much for your help!